# SCP not working with RegEx

Tags: scp, file-copy, download, upload

I've been trying to copy some remote files to localhost using regex expression, but it reads the regex as if it would be a regular string and does not find any files matching that.

Any ideas why?

file-download

```
#!/bin/bash

scp "student@172.18.186.10:/home/student/download-this/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.tar\.gz" .
```

I have also tried copying from localhost to remote device, but still the regex won't work with scp

file-upload

```
scp "/root/scripts/this[XYZ]_[0-9]{1,5}\.txt" fs@10.11.10.2:/home/fs/upload
```

[image: Local host files]

[image: Remote device files]

[image: Error messages]

Comment: expansion is performed by shell, what does `ls "/root/scripts/this[XYZ]_[0-9]{1,5}\.txt"`  (quotes) and `ls /root/scripts/this[XYZ]_[0-9]{1,5}\.txt` (no quotes) show ?

Comment: `ls "/root/scripts/this[XYZ]_[0-9]{1,5}\.txt"` -> `ls: cannot access '/root/scripts/this[XYZ]_[0-9]{1,5}\.txt': No such file or directory`.               `ls /root/scripts/this[XYZ]_[0-9]{1,5}\.txt` -> `ls: cannot access '/root/scripts/this[XYZ]_[0-9]5.txt': No such file or directory
 /root/scripts/thisY_91.txt`

Comment: How do you expect `{1,5}` regex quantifier to work in `ls` ? @Florin200217

Comment: I see it won't work, do you have any other suggestions? @GillesQuenot

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: in first case quote prevent expansion in second `pattern{1,5}` is expanded into `pattern1 pattern5` which is not what you want. (and work only for `this_Y91`.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, `scp` is not regex capable. Better use a `glob` like this:

```
scp 'student@172.18.186.10:/home/student/download-this/[a-zA-Z0-9]*.tar.gz' .
#   ^                                                                     ^
# need this single quotes
```

You can't use regex, instead, `scp` can handle `glob`, check

```
man bash | less +/'Pattern Matching'
```

To 'upload' a file by wildcard `*`:

```
scp [a-zA-Z0-9]*.tar.gz student@172.18.186.10:/home/student/upload-this/
```

Comment: And could you please tell me how would I do it for the upload comand?

Comment: `scp wildcard* user@remote/dir`/

Comment: Depending on what files exactly you have, something like `scp "/root/scripts/this"[XYZ]_[0-9]*.txt fs@10.11.10.2:/home/fs/upload`

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: Does it fits your needs ?